# Programmatic UINavigationController view transition displaying second view under first

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to programmatically create a navigation controller that transitions to another view on the tap of a button. In it's current state, when the button is tapped, the second view is placed "behind" the first view without a horizontal transition. Since I can still see the button at this point, if I tap the button again, the horizontal transition works now, but the second view still is placed behind the first view. Can any one please let me know what I'm missing?

Thanks!

**ViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UINavigationController {

    var btn: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        createUI()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func createUI() {
        btn = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 100, width: 100, height: 50))
        btn.backgroundColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
        btn.setTitle("GO", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        btn.addTarget(self, action: "go", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchDown)
        self.view.addSubview(btn)
    }

    func go() {
        println("go")
        var view = SecondViewController()
        self.pushViewController(view, animated: true)
    }

}
```

**SecondViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

    var lbl: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        createUI()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func createUI() {
        lbl = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: 200, width: 200, height: 50))
        lbl.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
        lbl.text = "LABEL"
        self.view.addSubview(lbl)
    }

}
```

[image: first view]

[image: second view under first view]

Comment: Seems like your "ViewController.swift" is actually UINavigationController - which shouldn't have any views on it. You should have UINavigationController, used to manage transitions and stack, and other ViewControllers (inheriting from UIViewController, not UINavigationController) for the content you want to display. Check out some tutorial, maybe this one - http://makeapppie.com/tag/uinavigationcontroller-in-swift/

Comment: Thanks @jovanjovanovic I used your advice to edit my files. I posted an update as an answer below. I'm not sure if I should mark my answer as correct or if I should have you post yours down there so I can mark your as the correct one?

Comment: I have added my comment as an answer - you can mark it as correct one. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like your "ViewController.swift" is actually UINavigationController - which shouldn't have any views on it. You should have UINavigationController, used to manage transitions and stack, and other ViewControllers (inheriting from UIViewController, not UINavigationController) for the content you want to display. Check out some tutorial, maybe this one - makeapppie.com/tag/uinavigationcontroller-in-swift

Answer (score 0):

Made the following updates to the files after jovanjovanovic's comment above. The initial controller is now set as a navigation controller with the root view parameter as the FirstViewController. Seems to be working properly now, though hopefully this is an acceptable way of doing this.

**AppDelegate.swift**

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
        var rootView = UINavigationController(rootViewController: FirstViewController())
        window?.rootViewController = rootView
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        return true
    }

    func applicationWillResignActive(application: UIApplication) {

    }

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {

    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(application: UIApplication) {
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(application: UIApplication) {
    }

}
```

**FirstViewController**

```
import UIKit

class FirstViewController: UIViewController {
    var btn: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        createUI()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func createUI() {
        btn = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 100, width: 100, height: 50))
        btn.backgroundColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
        btn.setTitle("GO 1", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        btn.addTarget(self, action: "go", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchDown)
        self.view.addSubview(btn)
    }

    func go() {
        println("go")
        var view = SecondViewController()
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(view, animated: true)
    }
}
```

**SecondViewController**

```
import UIKit

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

    var lbl: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        createUI()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func createUI() {
        lbl = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: 200, width: 200, height: 50))
        lbl.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
        lbl.text = "LABEL"
        self.view.addSubview(lbl)
    }

}
```